# Facing issue with few Tables which contains Dollar sign in the table name

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle11g, aws-dms

I am using aws dms service to migrate my on-prem data to the rds database . Basically it is a homogeneous migration from oracle to oracle.I am able to migrate my data perfectly. I only faced issue related to one of my which dms is not able to migrate and for the same i am not able to find anything in my cloudwatch logs.This table contains the dollar sign in the name that is **TEST$I_TABLE$I**

I am not sure what is the root cause. Does the $ would make any impact any pointer would be helpful.

I have cross verified my supplementory logging is enabled for all the colums for this table also

Answer (score 0):

No problem with dollars, as far as Oracle is concerned (Larry *loves* dollars):

```
SQL> create table TEST$I_TABLE$I (id number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

In your case, see whether enclosing its name into double quotes helps, e.g.

```
select * from "TEST$I_TABLE$I";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not creating the table from my end.DMS is creating and migrating the data.This is more specific to the Data migration service from aws

Comment: I was just trying to show that table names - that contain dollar sign - are valid (and demonstrated that by creating such a table). Therefore, it must be something else that causes problems. I don't know "Data migration service from aws", but I hope that someone else will be able to assist.